# tlsh module not found when running aws lambda function

Tags: python-3.x, aws-lambda, aws-lambda-layers

Tried to create dependent package of python package py-tlsh (like [here](https://github.com/trendmicro/tlsh)) through aws document to deploy packages with dependency by using `pip install py-tlsh`, it gave error

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-package.html

Got this error:

```
"errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'lambda_function': /var/task/tlsh.so: invalid ELF header"
```

Then tried to create `py-tlsh` package through docker, but then getting this error:

```
"errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'lambda_function': No module named 'tlsh'",
"errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError"
```

Can someone provide solution to resolve these errors and create `py-tlsh` package in aws lambda.

lamda_function.py

```
from tlsh import tlsh
import json

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    hash1 = "ABCDEF1234567890ABCDEF1234567890ABCDEF1234567890ABCDEF1234567890ABCDEF"
    hash2 = "ABCDEF1234567890ABCDEF1234567890ABCDEF1234567890ABCDEF1234567890ABC123"

    distance = tlsh.diff(hash1, hash2)
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps(distance)
    }
```

Looking for a solution without using AWS EC2 instance.